# If $3a+4b=x^2$ and $4a+3b=y^2$ Show that $7\mid a,b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$a,b\in \mathbb N$ And such that $3a+4b$ and $3b+4a$ are both perfect squares.

Show that $7\mid a,b$.

I don’t know how to solve this I’ve just made a system of equations:
$$\cases{3a+4b=x^2 \\ 3b+4a=y^2} \implies (3a+4b)(3b+4a)=(xy)^2$$
$$\iff 12a^2+25ab+12b^2=x^2y^2$$

Then I’ve tried to solve the quadratic equation but it didn’t help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now since you have changed the question

As noted by Haran $7|x,y$ so $$7|(4a+3b-3a-4b) \to 7|(a-b)$$ Now as $$7|x,y \to 49|x^2+y^2 \to 7|a+b$$ Thus $$7|(a+b+a-b)=2a\to 7|2a\to 7|a$$ similarly for $b$....

Answer (score 3):

Add the two equations, we have:
$$x^2+y^2 = 7(a+b)$$
Thus, $7 \mid (x^2+y^2)$. Use the fact that the quadratic residues modulo $7$ are only $0, 1,2,4$, and if two of these add to $0 \bmod{7}$, then both $x$ and $y$ are $0 \bmod{7}$. Thus, $7 \mid x,y$.

Next, use the fact that $7 \mid x,y$. Since $7 \mid (3a+4b)$, we get $a \equiv b \pmod{7}$. Moreover, from earlier, we can see that $49 \mid (x^2+y^2)$, so $7 \mid (a+b)$. Thus, $7 \mid a,b$.

Comment: Im sorry i have a typo in the question, see the edit

Comment: @Yassir I have made the required addition in the answer.